# What classical scores did Charlie Parker study?

Tags: jazz, charlie-parker

In the Miles Davis' autobiography, Davis talks about how Charlie Parker gave away his classical scores before he died a few days later. Does anyone know the specific names of these scores?

Comment: [This answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/98495/40842) describes the story, but attributes it to Charlie Parker instead of John Coltrane

Comment: Yes, I meant charlie parker. My question was based on that answer

Comment: A learned friend of mine suggested this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sonatas_and_Partitas_for_Solo_Violin_(Bach)

However he didn't have a firm source to quote, so for now we can only offer it as a suggestion rather than an answer.

Comment: IIRC, the chapter on Charlie Parker  in Leonard Feather's [From Satchmo to Miles](https://books.google.co.uk/books/about/From_Satchmo_To_Miles.html?id=e7NUtAEACAAJ&redir_esc=y)  quotes him mentioning a number of classical works and composers - Debussy etc, but I don't have the exact quote. that might point to what scores he could have had - or not

Comment: Classical composers that Parker had an interest in : Igor Stravinsky : the account of Stravinsky going to see CP perform at Birdland, abd CP interpolating part of Stravinsky's "Firebird suite" into his own tune "Koko" [NMAAM page, "Charlie Parker plays for Stravinsky"](https://nmaam.org/2016/06/02/charlie-parker-plays-for-stravinsky/).  He also admired experimental composer [Edgar Varese](https://www.jazzguitar.be/forum/players/79824-charlie-parker-edgard-varese.html), who was at one time a neighbour in Greenwich village.